# Get associated products

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I created a new module to create a section in admin panel. This module section has a sub-section "Associated products" where I can add one or more products to each item in that module.

I am able to get the field values using functions like

- `$combo->getName()`
- `$combo->getComments()`

But I am not able to get the associated products to that item using

```
$combo->getAssociatedProducts()
```

What I tried is as follows:

```
<?php $comboCollection = Mage::getResourceSingleton('combo/combo_collection'); ?>
<?php 
    foreach ($comboCollection as $combo) {
        zend_debug::dump($combo->getAssociatedProducts($combo));  //giving error       
    }
?>
```

PS: here `$combo` is not a product, it is just an item in the created module.

**Explanation**:

---

[image]

---

Comment: check what is rendered by `print_r($combo->getData());`. If you don't find associate_products named field then your `getAssociatedProducts` won't work.

Comment: yes I can't see associate_products.. How to do this now?

Comment: that means that you dont have associate_products field in your concerned db table of combo model/collection. So getting associated products depends on your module that how you are saving associated products information in db. You could explain more in your question that how this module is working.

Comment: @DeependraSingh I created this module using **Ultimate module creator** by Marius.. I updated my post with the screenshot.

Comment: and where in db associated product information is getting saved?

Comment: @DeependraSingh the mapping between the combo id and the associated product id is happening in `combo_combo_product` db table. The module is creating three tables. `combo_combo` (main table), `combo_combo_product` and `combo_combo_store`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you have model/collection `products` for table `combo_combo_product`. you should get collection for products and then filter it for current combo id of combo collection in this way

```
foreach ($comboCollection as $combo) {
    $associatedCollection = Mage::getResourceSingleton('combo/products_collection');
    //$associatedCollection = Mage::getModel('combo/products')->getCollection();
    $associatedCollection->addFieldToFilter('combo_id',array('eq' => $combo->getId()));
    foreach{$associatedCollection as $item){
       print_r($item->getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: they are not comma separated. check this screen shot where I am showing the structure of the table `combo_combo_product`. http://i.imgur.com/3dUEDUh.png

Comment: My module doesn't have `combo/products_collection` resource.. what should I do now?

Comment: thats why I have written 2 line for getting collection. comment first one and uncomment second one. If you even don't have model/collection for your table then you have to create model/collection

Comment: Can you please help me on how to create the product collection?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43231/discussion-between-deependra-singh-and-mr-green